# Forcefully open info page of facebook fan page on UIwebview in iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, uiwebview

I want to open info page through this link on uiwebview

http://www.facebook.com/TinRoofNashville?sk=info

But on my iPhone screen it looks like this

[image]

I want to open **info tab first not Activity tab** on webview, but the activity tab opens by default.

How can i do that? Info tab exist in more tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the link you give is opening the info page:

[image]

But as you can see, I am **not** logged in. Could it be the problem maybe?

In any case, you can use the delegate's `-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` and print in the console the URL when you tap on the "info" page, to see what changes.

Comment: I am log in from facebook. And pass url which i mention above. If you open this url on facebook or even browser. You will reach your destination but in iPhone, You will not :(

Comment: Yes, log out and try again to see if this is the problem.

Comment: I want to run my code with login. When i am log out, The result is fine. But i need to run my app with login with facebook

Comment: Then add the delegate method I wrote above and see in the console what URL are you visiting when you tap "info": `NSLog(@"Now visiting this URL: %@", request.URL.absoluteString);`

Comment: Thanks alot my final url is such like this:

[link](http://m.facebook.com/TinRoofNashville?id=133028623426021&_rdr#~!/TinRoofNashville?v=info&__user=1558423549)

Thanks for giving me time. I appreciate your effort :)